# Предложение об отставке модератора

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, модераторский-произвол

Формально у нас на сайте трое модераторов: один сотрудник компании Nicolas Chabanovsky и два назначенных pro-tempore: Nofate и Barmaley.

Первые двое очень много делают для сайта и для сообщества и активно участвуют в модерации. А вот Barmaley почему-то сторонится модерации и только изредка отвечает на вопросы.

Несколько раз в основном чате (куда он не заходит) поднимался вопрос о том, что он не соответствует статусу модератора ([пример](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21900609#21900609)). Но как-то этот вопрос спускали на тормозах. Предлагалось подождать до выборов, но выборы что–то не наступают.

Поднимаю этот вопрос снова. Я делаю это с тяжелым сердцем и удовольствия не испытываю. Но считаю, что так будет правильно. С чьей-то точки зрения я, наверное, перехожу грань дозволенного. Да будет так.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/186779/181472

> Как-то друг рассказывал историю про PHP прогершу, которая днем занималась тем что писала сайтики, а по ночам подрабатывала на трассе с дальнобойщиками.
>
> В общем выбор за вами. Но в любом случае оставаться там где вы сейчас - бессмысленно. Вы не составите конкуренции кооперативу девиц "Сосулька" :)

Ладно, я и сам пару раз иронизировал над PHP-разработчиками (а они надо мной, тестировщиком). Но такое мне очень неприятно видеть. Тем более дико, что это ответ модератора сайта. Пусть ответ старый. Но он обнаруживает такие черты, с которыми в обычном порядке невозможно быть избранным в модераторы.

В нагрузку:

- Нет в чате, где обсуждается развитие и модерация сайта
- Нет на Мете, последний ответ 23 июня.
- С июля [почти нет активности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley?tab=activity&sort=reviews) в очереди проверок.
- (Вопрос к остальным модераторам, а сколько проверенных тревог есть?)

Теперь цитирую: [Справка — Кто такие модераторы.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

> Мы ожидаем от модераторов следующих качеств:
>
> - ...уважение к товарищам по сообществу в словах и делах;

А мы как раз видим проявление неуважения.

> - умение выполнять ненавязчивую, но твердую модерацию сообщества, вести его и решать редкие (как хочется надеяться) споры и исключения.

Модерация отсутствует.

> ...
>    Идеальный модератор делает очень немногое, но все, что он делает, приносит значительную пользу, заметно сообществу и является очень целенаправленным.

Ограничимся «очень немногое» — по части модерации это так.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Вот здесь говорится о том, что сообщество вправе инициировать отставку модератора: [Handling Calls to Remove a Moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/296059).

При всём этом Barmaley — ценный участник сайта, отличный специалист по Java и Android и дает хорошие ответы.

Давайте у нас будет всего два модератора, зато исключительно настоящих, а? И пожалуйста, давайте не ждать до выборов. Мы как будто бережём Barmaley от огорчения, позволяя ему спокойно сложить с себя полномочия в конце беты. Я так не хочу, ни дня больше.

В отставку!

Comment: Если вы против — я жду ваших ответных аргументов.

Comment: Мне не кажется, что отставка модератора имеет смысл, если он не проводит действий, воспринимаемых большинством как деструктивные. Поэтому пункты «в нагрузку», как мне кажется, не являются строгой аргументацией против.

Comment: А обсуждение в чате, не закончившееся убеждением администрации, показывает, что его действия не воспринимаются **большинством** как деструктивные. Ergo: пользы от изгнания никакой.

Comment: @VladD: Раз - он занимает место одного **настоящего** модератора.

Comment: @VladD: Два - лучше никакого модератора, чем плохой.

Comment: @VladD: Три - почитайте комментарии. С таким стилем общения можно быть участником, но не лицом сообщества.

Comment: _Занимает место_? Нету технической возможности иметь и четвёртого модератора?

Comment: @VladD: да, именно так. Я предлагал ещё летом заменить его действующим модератором — нет, нельзя было.

Comment: По этому поводу предлагаю получить официальный комментарий Николаса.

Comment: Заметьте, что тот ответ, который вы критикуете, был дан задолго до того, как Хэшкод превратился в SO. Я не считаю правильным оценивать модератора по детским грехам. Я может быть в детстве вообще девочек за косички дёргал, что ж теперь, вспомнить и это <s>и заминусовать</s>?

Comment: @VladD но не до того, как человечество выработало идею взаимного уважения. И он не был тогда в школе.

Comment: Всё равно не аргумент. Я даже во время участия на сайте (да не шокирует это присутствующих) неуважительно ругался матом. И что, это аннулирует меня как потенциального модератора? Кто из нас без греха, пусть первый бросит камень в Бармалея.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, неудачный  аргумент против. Нет в ответе Бармалея никакого неуважения. Ответ надо воспринимать конструктивно, это помощь разнывшемуся коллеге (и "PHP сосульки" тут просто к слову, для приободрения ТС).

Answer (score 28):

Поскольку вопрос касается меня лично, вынужден заявить свою точку зрения: я действительно подал прошение о добровольной отставке.

У меня нет ни сил ни времени модерировать сообщество. Иногда по мере сил и способностей я занимаюсь модерацией, но увы, привычки делать это постоянно у меня нет (и видимо не появится). Я боролся с этим, но не получилось. 2-3 часа в день - это выше моих сил, тем более, что основное бремя модерирования ложится на темы связанные с HTML/JavaScript/PHP вопросами - то есть темами которые я не очень люблю.

И соответственно, как человек ответственный, я подал таковое прошение в адрес @NicolasChabanovsky.

Будущему модератору (модераторам) - просьба правильно оценивать свои силы.

**Update:** 
Касательно поста по-поводу дальнобойщиков и "сосулек". Не считаю, что такой юмор в чем-то противоречит правилам сайта. Здесь же не собрание членов политбюро или папской комиссии по морали. Ну и тем более, какое это имеет отношение к модерированию? Это просто пост, который если нравится плюсуют, если нет минусуют. На текущий момент 17 плюсов и 6 минусов (причем 5 или 6 откликов за последние сутки, после того как кто-то вытащил это некропост на свет божий), топик-стартёр ответ принял - следовательно он его устраивает. Буду крайне рад, если @NickVolynkin разъяснит мне всю глубину моего грехопадения.

Comment: А может передумаешь и останешься модератором?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Всё достаточно просто: такие шутки неуместны в контексте профессиональной уважительной беседы. Для обычного участника это было бы просто ошибкой. К модератору требования гораздо выше — он не должен сознательно нарушать правила сайта. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @Barmaley: Отдельное спасибо за то, что вы появились в этом достаточно неприятном топике.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я думаю, что у нас слегка отличаются наши представления о профессиональной беседе. Терпеть не могу двойные стандарты: когда мы ведем одни беседы в переговорной у  ген.директора, а другие в курилке с мужиками. Останусь при своем мнении, ваше мнение я также услышал.

Answer (score 20):

#### Должен выразиться *против* данного решения

Доводы такие.

- Согласно [Макиавелли](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8,_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE):

  > Люди, веря, что новый правитель окажется лучше, охотно восстают против старого, но вскоре они на опыте убеждаются, что обманулись, ибо новый правитель всегда оказывается хуже старого.

  Хотя эти строки используются немного в другом контексте и правителей, конечно же, у нас нет, но нам они тоже подходят: революции в большинстве своем приводят к более плачевному состоянию, чем было до них. Снятие  @Barmaley не приведет к улучшению ситуации в сообществе, как результат, в этом действии нет смысла.
- На мой взгляд, стоит подождать несколько недель до аттестации сообщества и официальных выборов в модераторы. Напомню, в момент выхода сообщества из беты, «pro-tempore» модераторы будут сняты, а сообщество, по средством голосования, выберет новых. Конечно же, у настоящих модераторов есть возможность выдвинуть свою кандидатуру, и это приветствуется!
  Все в компании убеждены, что сообщество Stack Overflow на русском давно может пройти аттестацию. Торможение процесса идет по вине компании: 1) я не успеваю проверить все переводы и исправить ошибки и неточности, 2) существует «очередь» сайтов на выход из беты, так как переход требует много внимания *определенных сотрудников компании*. Постараюсь поднять вопрос аттестации в ближайшее время на планерке и уточнить кратчайшие возможные сроки.

**В дополнение.**

Текущих модераторов выбрало сообщество голосованием. Позволю себе напомнить, что именно сообщество в 2013 году выбрало трех участников представлять общие интересы и следить за порядком:

- [@Nofate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate);
- [@Barmaley](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley);
- [@ReinRaus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/481/reinraus).

После перехода на новую платформу, к сожалению, @ReinRaus принял решение далее участвовать как «рядовой–пользователь». Уверен, сообщество с уважением отнеслось к принятому решению.

После того, как скорректировались правила сообщества, из личной переписки с @Barmaley я вынес, что в следствие произошедших изменений, сообщество хоть и осталось интересным, но не является настолько близким как ранее, в следствие недопустимости некоторых форматов построения диалога. Как результат, на сколько я понял, нет желания принимать активное участие в модерации.

*Почему же тогда просто не убрать «ромб»?*

*Два модератора лучше чем один!* @Barmaley не просто отлично понимает правила Stack Overflow, но и является ответственным человеком, который готов прийти на помощь сообществу в нужный момент (например, @Barmaley заблокировал намного больше вредителей на ХэшКоде, чем я или любой другой модератор). Уверен, что в случае острой необходимости он сможет пополнить команду активных модераторов сообщества.

Comment: Жаль, не могу плюсануть дважды.

Comment: Barmaley может и понимает, но не следует правилам. И вы проигнорировали большую часть моих аргументов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ни в коем случае! Все замечания были учтены, и мне нечего возразить. Вы совершенно обосновано и верно подчеркнули проблему. В ответе я лишь попытался выразить, почему не вижу крайней надобности в этом действии, и буду рад посветить один рабочий день более насущным, на мой взгляд, проблемам сообщества.

Comment: Пост про [Муки модератора](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1787) лишний раз показывает, насколько Barmaley не в курсе правил сайта и системы его работы. Предлагает то, что полностью противоречит правилам SO и явно не понимает, как работает Дух сообщества. Я очень надеюсь, что никогда не случится необходимости, чтобы он активно модерировал сайт.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: пользователь сайта не принимает никакого участия в сообществе и не разделяет его правила, но наделён правами модератора. Он просто дискредитирует должность модератора.

Comment: Интересно наблюдать, как поменялось мое восприятие с тех пор. Прочитал сейчас цитату Макиавелли и связанные рассуждения - поменял плюс на минус. Цитата исходит из того, что все правители плохие (в той или иной степени). Но наша реальность такова, что есть гауссово распределение, где-то посредине будут "средние" потенциальные модераторы, слева - похуже, справа - получше. С большой вероятностью новый будет "средним" (в хорошем смысле) - обычным адекватным человеком. И даже если будет плохой, его можно заменить на нового (если ввести нормальную практику - ограничение срока и регулярных выборов).

Comment: @insolor На сколько помню, там контекст высказывания был в том, что: (1) Новый правитель всегда должен заплатить тем, кто помогал ему свергать старого и, как результат, людям будет житься хуже, (2) все люди действительно одинаковые (то, о чем пишите вы), но к производительности старого руководства еще надо прийти. То есть общество получает большую просадку по многим параметрам, а приходит в лучшем случае к тому же, что имело.

Answer (score 8):

Когда отставка вот прямо **нужна**:

1. На занимаемую должность тратятся ресурсы (зарплата, транспорт, кабинет...);
2. Занимаемая должность никем не дублируется и человек "мешает" более полезному кандидату;
3. Текущий исполнитель наносит явный вред своими действиями.

Что вижу я? Практически ничего. Barmaley не появляется на сайте, не вредит, есть не просит и сайт, при этом, не летит в пропасть поскольку модерация осуществляется успешно. Да, модератор должен быть хорошим примером для сообщества. Но сейчас он и плохим не является.

Можно было бы отстранить в "надзидание" последователям, только зачем?

PS. Я не помню досконально все требования к модераторам, но судя по активности (особенно в последнее время), на ближайших выборах топикстартеру самое место быть "бубновым"

Answer (score 8):

Я на СО новичок, всего две недели.
Работа "злобного" модератора Barmaley оставляет приятное впечатление.
В отличие от непонятных мне дрязг.

Это только на первый взгляд модератора легко заменить. Но квалифицированные люди всегда востребованы, и не каждый на это пойдёт.

Чувство меры хорошо в меру.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, он отстранился от модерации сайта в начале лета. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы понимаете под работой модератора Barmaley?

Comment: Приведу конкретный, легко проверяемый эпизод. Мой первый топ в ответах, тема "Поиск числа, имеющего наибольшее число делителей" (математика алгоритм числа). Я не был уверен, как лучше представить результаты - в виде реального HTML-кода или в виде его имитации с тегом <pre>, и на какое-то время оставил оба варианта, причём второй - дублирующим ответом. А потом увидел, что модератор Barmaley удалил менее удачный дубль. Полагаю, я ответил... А теперь вопрос к Вам: Вы всегда сначала минусуете, а потом разбираетесь в ситуации? До Вашего вопроса мой ответ имел +2. Это из легко проверяемых вещей...

Comment: там Barmaley отредактировал вам форматирование кода, а потом вы сами удалили вопрос. В истории: « за Сообщение удалено проголосовали Yuri Negometyanov».

Comment: Ответ прочитал, значит разобрался в ситуации.  И действительно поставил минус, т.к. не согласен с вашей аргументацией. Вы подразумеваете, что этот модератор — квалифицированный, и что мало кто согласится заниматься модерацией. Однако я не согласен про квалификацию — потому и бью тревогу. Знаю полтора десятка участников, которые гораздо более квалифицированы в модерации на ru.SO, так как занимаются ей каждый день. Знаю также, что есть желающие взять на себя обязанности модератора, и на предстоящих выборах мне есть за кого голосовать.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Отредактировать с комментарием "<!-- вырезано несколько сотен строк злым модератором-->" -это удалить. Теперь я разобрался с Вашим вопросом: налицо неуважение к правилам сайта и упорство в намерении подменить мнение сообщества своим. И мне как раз нужна медалька "Критик", так что ничего личного...

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Проясняю свою позицию: У Вас была возможность лично убедить модератора в своей правоте, а не будоражить простых участников сообщества этим вопросом.

Comment: Думаю, вы преувеличиваете значение голосов против. Я не обижусь на ваши, да и вам не стоило. Голоса это просто "поддерживаю"/"не поддерживаю", их можно за день 2х40 штук поставить.

Comment: что касается ваших обвинений в подмене мнения - они безосновательны. Мета предназначена для обсуждений, в том числе неприятных. А другие участники достаточно умны, чтобы не перепутать своё мнение с моим.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Спасибо.

Comment: и вам спасибо за обсуждение.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31939/discussion-between-yuri-negometyanov-and-nick-volynkin).

Comment: Ещё хотел бы уточнить, что я понимаю под модерацией. Похоже, мы говорим о разных вещах. Отредактировать вопрос или ответ - это здорово, но это может сделать почти любой участник сайта (кажется, с 15 репутации). Многие другие функции тоже могут выполнять рядовые участники с высокой репутацией. Но есть то, что доступно только модератору: е' разбирать тревоги, банить или наставлять нарушителей, и т.п. Именно таких действий я жду от модератора

Comment: Я описал конкретный эпизод, который выпал из Вашего поля зрения. Наверняка есть и другие эпизоды. А закрывать глаза и говорить "не вижу" - это несерьёзно. Кстати: в разобранном эпизоде я был нарушителем и получил твёрдое  и тактичное  наставление. Что укрепило моё мнение о Barmaley как о хорошем модераторе

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov вы оцениваете действия модератора по одному случаю, причем по тривиальной правке кода. Правка чужих сообщений тут доступна каждому. Подправить форматирование кривого чужого сообщения - это обязанность каждого, а не только модератора. И у меня, и у Ника таких правок сотни - причем чаще всего это правки сообщений новичков. Но вы же не предлагаете вот прямо сейчас выдать нам модераторские ромбы? :)

Comment: @PashaPash Нет, не предлагаю. Но при открытии вопроса модераторы де-факто (и Вы в том числе) обычно пытаются уточнить вопрос и спрашивают: "А что конкретно Вы пытались сделать?" И именно в этом суть моего отношения к вопросу.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov это делаю все, кто пытается дать ответ на вопрос.   Т.е. практически все активные участники. Функции модератора на SO совсем не в этом. Модераторы здесь не ради сортировки/открытия/закрытия/удаления вопросов и ответов. Всем этим занимаются обычные участники. Основная функция модератора - разбирать случаи, когда остальные участники попытались, но не смогли решить проблему.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov у вас через пару плюсов откроется доступ к очередями проверки - поймете, что я имею ввиду

Comment: @PashaPash Именно так. И я это делаю по отношению к данному вопросу. При этом негативная оценка ответа в соответствии с хинтом означает "Данный ответ не является полезным". Я воспринимаю это как попытку отмахнуться от моего мнения.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov на самом SO негативная отметка означает неодобрение поведения. Здесь, на мете - несогласие с изложенным в ответе. не обращайте внимания на тултипы.

Comment: @PashaPash Если уж такие простые термины имеют недокументированное значение, то я не вижу смысла в дальнейшем обсуждении вопроса.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov есть целый раздел справки, а ещё мой многословный пост на Мете о том, что означают голоса на основном сайте и на Мете, на вопросах и на "ответах. Так что всё документировано. Читайте. :)

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov любой тултип можно изменить. я, например, просто не обращал внимания на тултипы на vote down. если вас они сбили с толку - создайте пост на мете, опишите проблему и предложите свой вариант - и текст поменяют

Answer (score 5):

Не вижу ничего плохого в его модераторстве. Даже если он не проявляет особого модераторского усердия, я не вижу причин лишать его статуса модератора - ведь никакой вредительской активности с его стороны нет.

Вот если это влияет на количество модераторов - что их должно быть ровно 3, то, вероятно, замена имела бы смысл. Но такого ограничения, насколько я знаю, нет.

Что касается возможных отклонений от правил, то, по-моему, модераторский взгляд с другой стороны от правил имеет смысл и пользу для сообщества.

Что касается приведённого сообщения, то не вижу в нём ничего криминального. Там явно не ставилась цель никого оскорбить или обидеть, просто в такой форме он высказал свои мысли. Причём, мысли правильные. Я один из поставивших тому ответу плюс. Моё мнение, что если злонамеренных целей изначально не ставилось, то и не надо их приписывать и на что-то обижаться. Важна не форма, а содержание и намерения.

Comment: Вам нравится модератор, который не модерирует, потому что вы не поддерживаете некоторые текущие правила сообщества. Так давайте лучше между собой будем правила обсуждать, зачем нам для этого недействующий модератор?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, от него вред есть или нет? Мало модераторов? Можно же выбрать ещё, не лишая никого статуса модератора. В чём профит именно лишения?

Comment: в данном случае бездействие - это вред. Модератор должен быть активным. Он берет на себя  обязательство принимать активное участие в жизни сообщества. Статус модератора это не привилегия, это прежде всего бремя и долг. Это действие, а не свойство.

Comment: @NickVolynkin `бездействие - это вред` Почему? Если модератор ничего не делает, нельзя ли просто представлять, что его не существует? Я не вижу практическую разницу между сообществом с двумя активными модераторами и тем же сообщестом с дополнительным неактивным модератором.

Comment: @PeterOlson: всё это время вместо него мог бы быть другой, действующий модератор pro-tempore.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ты ещё ни разу прямо не сказал, что модераторов должно быть ровно 3. Неужели нельзя просто выбрать четвёртого?

Comment: @Qwertiy: выбрать можно только на выборах. А назначить ещё полгода назад следовало бы кого-то другого.

Comment: @NickVolynkin В вопросе, ваше предложение вот такое: `Давайте у нас будет всего два модератора` Пожалуй, за последнее время другой человек мог бы быть более подходящим модератором, но зачем теперь обсуждать о том, что следовало произойти полгода назад? Какая польза от отставки сейчас, если после неё практически ничего не изменится?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Делает. Я как раз поднимаю старые темы, так что вижу.

Answer (score 2):

Просто "нет".​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

Модератерство на SO пожизненное.

Одна из проблем при получении звания модератора - ромб приклепляется не только к будущим действиям, но и ко всем постам и сообщениям в прошлом. Причем даже к тем, которые явно противоречат духу/правилам сайта на момент назначения.

Это очень заметно при разгребании старых вопросов. Например, @NicolasChabanovsky♦ является автором огромного количества оффтопика. Причем закрыть/удалить/провести через очередь проверки такие вопросы достаточно тяжело - люди просто боятся минусовать или закрывать что-то, возле чего нарисован ромб.

Это единственный "вред" который теоретически наносить неактивный модератор. Но лично я не считаю его сколь-либо значимым.

Стоит так же учесть, что Barmaley был модератором еще до переезда на SO, и что при снятии ромба некоторые его комментарии / ответы / действия могут начать выглядеть неправильно - например, у кого-то наверняка не поймет, почему старые вопросы мог закрывать и удалять какой-то обычный участник.

Comment: В общем, все против - ура!

Comment: "Напомню, в момент выхода сообщества из беты, «pro-tempore» модераторы будут сняты" - Nicolas Chabanovsky, в соседнем ответе.

Comment: @NickVolynkin сам по себе процесс беты подразумевает, что назначенные модераторы активно модерируют, и не производят кучу постов, рядом с которыми наличие ромба вызывает сомнения. я бы оставил ромб всем текущим модерам и после выхода из беты.

Comment: @PashaPash: про бету - полностью согласен. Только Barmaley не модерирует. Nofate я бы охотно оставил модератором, а Barmaley - нет.

Comment: @PashaPash Не вижу проблем с голосом против сообщения от модератора, тем более старых. Если вы видите, что кто-то почему-то не закрывает или не удаляет сообщения от модераторов, которые не соответствуют тематики и настоящим правилам сайта, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь указывать на необходимость правильности действий и равноправия в сообществе!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я не стесняюсь, просто очень забавно наблюдать, как народ аккуратно обходит поставленую тревогу LQ на любое ваше сообщение :)

Comment: @PashaPash Скидывайте такие сообщения в чат, я постараюсь помочь!