# Отстранение модератора от модераторской деятельности

Tags: поддержка, модерация

Что должен сделать или не сделать ромбовидный модератор, чтобы потерять свой ромб и превратиться обратно в <s>тыкву</s> рядового участника?

Какие примеры знает сеть Stack Exchange на этот счёт?

Comment: "_Какие примеры знает сеть Stack Exchange на этот счёт?_" -  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1785/240512

Comment: @VadimTagil это только один наш отечественный пример, но уже лучше, чем ничего.

Comment: @alexolut на enSO ромб могут забрать, если модератор не модерирует. даже если он при этом активен как обычный участник.

Comment: @PashaPash а у нас в квартире газ?

Comment: @alexolut нет. у нас слишком мало модераторов, чтобы кто-то забил. Сейчас доберем еще двоих, и тогда узнаем.

Comment: @PashaPash плохо без газа-то ;) на ответ наскребёте информации или ограничитесь комментариями?

Comment: @alexolut нет никакой информации. пока только один прецедент потери ромба. у нас за неактивность ромбы не забирали (и, судя по всему, не должны).

Comment: За любое злоупотребление инструментами модератора в личных целях. Например, если посмотреть и слить личные данные.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да что же вы всё в комментариях, да в комментариях

Comment: @alexolut не соответствует моему стандарту хорошего ответа.

Comment: @alexolut а стандарт такой: ответ должен быть по возможности полный, точный, подтвержденный источниками, структурированный и лаконичный. Слишком долго такой писать.

Answer (score 3):

Слишком поздно, но в 2015 году на Server Fault [модератор HopelessN00b был снят с должности](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8054/abrupt-change-in-moderation-staff) из-за массового закрытия вопросов, которые он считал оффтопиком, без предварительного обсуждения на мете и с другими модераторами.